# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'secret' referenced before assignment. AWS secrets manager python code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cloud

This is the python code from AWS secret manager. I am not sure why I am getting the error guys.
I have tried defining "secrets" outside the function as a global variable then declaring it in the function in vain.

Please assist me.

```
import boto3
import base64
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import json

def get_secret():

# Create a Secrets Manager client
session = boto3.session.Session()
client = session.client(
    service_name='secretsmanager',
    region_name=region_name
)

# In this sample we only handle the specific exceptions for the 'GetSecretValue' API.
# See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
# We rethrow the exception by default.

try:
    get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
        SecretId=secret_name
    )
except ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'DecryptionFailureException':
        # Secrets Manager can't decrypt the protected secret text using the provided KMS key.
        # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
        raise e
    elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InternalServiceErrorException':
        # An error occurred on the server side.
        # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
        raise e
    elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidParameterException':
        # You provided an invalid value for a parameter.
        # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
        raise e
    elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidRequestException':
        # You provided a parameter value that is not valid for the current state of the resource.
        # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
        raise e
    elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ResourceNotFoundException':
        # We can't find the resource that you asked for.
        # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
        raise e
else:
    # Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.
    # Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated
    if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
        secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
    else:
        secret = base64.b64decode(get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary'])

return json.loads(secret)
```

I get the error below:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'secret' referenced before assignment.
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question. What should happen if there is a ClientError which hasn't one of the codes you check in the except-block?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the else statement worked for me.

```
else:
    # Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.
    # Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated
    if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
        return json.loads(get_secret_value_response['SecretString'])
    
    return json.loads(base64.b64decode(get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary']))
```

My understanding of the error is the variable 'secret' is local to the else block but it's being referenced outside of it. The above is just one option to correct it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the code. This problem occurs due to wrong/missing aws credentials. Please check your credentials, make sure you are connected aws and try again.